# Probability of a random divisor of a given integer $n$

Tags: random-functions

Suppose we have a given integer $n$. We randomly pick an integer $k$, where $k\leq n$. Then What is the probability that $k$ divides $n$?

Comment: Very small.  It is technically d(n) ,the number of divisors of n, divided by n.  The quantity d(n) varies from (for n > 1) 2 to log base 2  of n.  How d(n) varies over a range has been studied, in general the number is about log(log(n)), and the literature tells you how it varies from this.  Sometimes $\tau$ is used instead of d for this function.  Gerhard "Check Out The Chances Online" Paseman, 2015.09.25

Comment: Hmm.  The average of the  d(i) for i from 1 to n is larger than I expected.  I will need to check what is counted by log(log(n)).  Gerhard "Odds Bigger Than I Thought" Paseman, 2015.09.25

Comment: @GerhardPaseman, the number of prime divisors. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Erd%C5%91s%E2%80%93Kac_theorem

Comment: Thanks Will.  I've temporarily lost the capacity to distinguish between $\omega$ and d.  Gerhard "Hopefully It Will Come Back" Paseman, 2015.09.25

Comment: If you allow negative $k$, this greatly reduces the changes.

Answer (score -1):

There seems to be an answer. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Divisor.